# Sterling database not persist on Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, sterling-db

I followed sterling database examples from several persons. Neither of them seems to work out for me. When I persist some stuff on my database everything clearly gets persisted using sterling (on my phone, not emulator) when debugging. However when I relaunch my app the database is empty. Is somebody else experiencing the same problem. Or does someone have a complete working example. I know my serializing and saving works... As long as I don't relaunch my app loading my state works...

Code in my app.cs

```
    public static ISterlingDatabaseInstance Database { get; private set; }
    private static SterlingEngine _engine;
    private static SterlingDefaultLogger _logger;

    private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        ActivateEngine();
    }

    // Code to execute when the application is activated (brought to foreground)
    // This code will not execute when the application is first launched
    private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        ActivateEngine();
    }

    // Code to execute when the application is deactivated (sent to background)
    // This code will not execute when the application is closing
    private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        DeactivateEngine();
    }

    // Code to execute when the application is closing (eg, user hit Back)
    // This code will not execute when the application is deactivated
    private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DeactivateEngine();
    }



    private void ActivateEngine()
    {
        _engine = new SterlingEngine();
        _logger = new SterlingDefaultLogger(SterlingLogLevel.Information);
        _engine.Activate();
        Database = _engine.SterlingDatabase.RegisterDatabase<SokobanDb>();
    }

    private void DeactivateEngine()
    {
        _logger.Detach();
        _engine.Dispose();
        Database = null;
        _engine = null;
    }
```

Code in my viewModel

```
    public void LoadState(int level)
    {
        var levelState = App.Database.Load<LevelState>(level);
        if (levelState != null)
        {
            //TODO: check if game started, then create board from boardstring property else create new board
            //Labyrint = new Labyrint(Factory.CreateBoard());
            NewGame(level);
        }
        else
        {
            NewGame(level);
        }
    }

    public void SaveState()
    {
        var levelState = new LevelState { LevelId = _level, Moves = Labyrint.Moves, Board = Labyrint.ToString() };
        App.Database.Save(levelState);
        App.Database.Flush(); //Required to clean indexes etc.
    }
```

Comment: Are you aware that built-in database exists since Mango?

Comment: Yes I'm aware, but I don't need a relational database like SQL CE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default Sterling database uses an in-memory driver. To persist, pass it an isolated storage driver. Per the documentation guide quickstart:

https://sites.google.com/site/sterlingdatabase/sterling-user-guide/getting-started

The code looks like this:

_databaseInstance = _engine.SterlingDatabase.RegisterDatabase(new IsolatedStorageDriver());

Note the instance of the isolated storage driver being passed in. That should do it for you.

When in doubt, take a look at the unit tests shipped with the source. Those contain tons of examples of memory, isolated storage, etc. to show various patterns for setting it up.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy! I was just in the middle of writing up this exact question. Forgot to look at the unit tests--would have saved me at least an hour. :)